# Can't add segmented control to toolbar via code using a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app I used to have a navigation bar at the top and toolbar at the bottom with 4 buttons in total. I also had a segmented control in the toolbar that would be shown when one of the other buttons is toggled. This all works fine using `IBOutlet`s etc.

One of the buttons is a crude user tracking button which I've now replaced with `MKUserTrackingButton`. To get this to work I had to add it via code as so (`bottomToolBar` is an `IBOutlet` of `UIToolBar`):

```
[bottomToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackButton, flexible, keysButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

This works fine, but of course the segmentedcontrol (called mapTypeControl) now longer shows, so I did this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *segmentControlButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mapTypeControl];
[bottomToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackButton, flexible, segmentControlButton, flexible, keysButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

But the segment control does not show. If I add it to the navigation bar it shows, but I just can't get it to show in the toolbar.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are the other buttons showing?

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more code to really understand what is happening here, and I am not clear on why you are doing some of the buttons in code and some in IB. However, why not keep a reference to the `UIBarButtonItem` that contains the segmented control in IB? Then you do not have to destroy it and recreate it again, you can just insert it in the array that is set on the bottomToolBar.